# CVlm {DAAG}: setting printit = FALSE causes an issue - object 'sumss' not found

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, cross-validation

I am using the `CVlm {DAAG}` and I wanted to set the `printint=FALSE` since the default says

```
printit if TRUE, output is printed to the screen
```

I tried to run the function with both `plotit` and `printit` to `FALSE` but then I found the error: ***`sumss` variable not found***.

Is there a way to actually set the `printit` and `plotit` to `FALSE` since I do not want the plot nor the table printed on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding the latest DAAG_1.22 updated on Sep 3, 2015**

Relax, you have found a bug for `CVlm {DAAG}`. I am sure you have set both `printit` and `plotit` to `FALSE`, which reproduces the issue. Consider the following reproducible example:

```
library(DAAG)
CVlm(printit = FALSE)  ## OK, plot generated, no ANOVA table printed
CVlm(plotit = FALSE)  ## OK, ANOAV table printed, no plot generated
CVlm(printit = FALSE, plotit = FALSE)  ## Oops...
# Error in CVlm(printit = FALSE, plotit = FALSE) : object 'sumss' not found
```

Now, a quick scan of the source code reveals the issue. Local variable `sumss` is defined at:

```
if (printit | plotit) {
    sumss <- 0
    sumdf <- 0
    ## ...blablabla
    }
```

i.e., either `printit` and `plotit` needs be `TRUE` to declare and initialize `sumss`. However, in the very end of `CVlm`:

```
attr(data, "ms") <- sumss/sumdf
attr(data, "df") <- sumdf
```

there is no `if` condition to protect them. Therefore, when you reach those lines, you get "variable not found" error.

I am not package author or maintainer so I am not keen on fixing this issue. I just suggest you to keep `plotit = TRUE`.

---

I saw your new edit to clarify the question. If you want neither plot nor print, you have to modify `CVlm` function yourself, by removing the two `attr` lines mentioned above. It looks like package author is not keen on maintaining this package, so asking for a bug fix seems desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `devtools::install_github('gokceneraslan/DAAG')` to install the fixed version.