# R cross-validation package cv.lm, shows Error when set plotit=TRUE, printit=FALSE

Tags: r, cross-validation

when set the plotit=FALSE and printit=FALSE

`c <- cv.lm(resdata,x,m=5, plotit=FALSE, printit=FALSE)`

Error:

````
  object 'sumss' not found```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CVlm {DAAG}: setting printit = FALSE causes an issue - object 'sumss' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700867/cvlm-daag-setting-printit-false-causes-an-issue-object-sumss-not-found)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error of the package when you set both plotit and printit to FALSE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40703773/8071529